# Is using a push notification containing a link to the playstore against google play policy?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-play, onesignal, google-play-console

I'm using onesignal in my apps for notifications and there is option to send a notification with a URL. I want to use this to send a notification with a link to allow users to download my new apps. Is this allowed by google play policy?

Comment: There will be no problem. Use the payload for the same.

Comment: I tried to reword the question to make it more understandable. Hopefully I have not changed what the original question was asking - it was a little hard to understand

Answer (score 0):

Stack overflow is not the place for App store policy questions. Nevertheless, you can find all of Google's policy information on the [Developer Policy Center](https://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy).

On this, under [malicious behavior](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/malicious-behavior/) it says: "*The following are explicitly prohibited: ...
Apps or SDKs that download executable code, such as dex files or native code, from a source other than Google Play.*"